# Access HTTP2 headers from a @grpc/grpc-js Handler

Tags: node.js, grpc, http2

I have a [@grpc/grpc-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grpc/grpc-js) server. It includes a handler for a method that looks like this

```
server = new grpc.Server()
server.addService(proto.GrpcTester.service, {
    myMethod(call, callback) {
       callback(null, {hello:"world"})
    }
})
```

Is there a way to access the HTTP2 request headers that were set when this request was made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `call` object passed to the `myMethod` function in that example code has a `metadata` property that contains the request headers.